# Index method in Django's Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django template I need to return the index of an item in a list.(index method in python) What is a way I could do this. Do I need to use a custom filter? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this inside a foor loop, you can use [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable. Otherwise, you can use python to calculate it and pass it in the context to the template.